# How to take an object with textures applied in nodes and put it into unity

Tags: rendering, node-editor, unity

So I used the sapling add-on to create a well detailed tree. Under the curves tab I check the Use UV for mapping box and the went into cycles render mode. I then opened up the node editor and applied the textures to the tree with nodes. When I went into render view all of the textures were in place and correct. But when I finally saved the blender file and the put it into unity it didn't process the textures. Do I need to uvmap the tree instead of applying the textures through node editor, for it to show up in unity. I would very much appreciate if someone could clear this up for me.

Thanks, Nova

Comment: The various exporters cannot handle Cycles materials so Blender Internal should be used for now when setting up textures that will be exported.  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/exporting-cycles-rendered-models-to-be-used-in-opengl/19326#19326

Comment: Also, you may need to bake some of the textures.  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24048/create-a-low-poly-mesh-with-high-detailed-textures/24127#24127
 http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24111/making-texture-atlas-for-only-some-part-of-objects/24112#24112